# Spring Data/SQL Query to find all matches by collection

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

Could you please advise how to write query in Spring Data JPA repository? Here is the situation:
I have 2 Entities: Customer and Product with relationship 'OneToMany' - means one Customer may have many products. In code it looks like Customer entity has Set products and Product has reference to Customer customer, very simple. If I retrieve Customer from DB JSON would look like this:    `{"id":10, "name":'John Smith',"personalCode":12345678,"products":[ {"id":15,"type":"productType1"}, {"id":20,"type":"productType2"}] }`

The question is how can I write query to DB to find all customers whose products match passed products collection? For example I want to find all customers who owns products with type1 and type2. THANKS!

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String name;

private int age;

private String personalCode;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Country country;

private String internetBankUserId;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private CustomerType type;

@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@SortNatural
private SortedSet<Product> products = new TreeSet<>();
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements Comparable<Product>{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ProductType type;

@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
private Customer customer;
```

Comment: Please check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60380128/16572295. It might suit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Customer c join  c.products p where p.type in :products 
       and SIZE(c.products) >= :count")
Set<Customer> findAllByProductType (@Param("products")Set<ProductType> products,
                                    @Param("count") Integer count );
```